# Montage / Join 2 TIFF images in a 2 col x 1 row tile without losing quality

Tags: r, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I have 2 same size, dimensions, and resolution images in TIFF (6400x6400 pixels, 800x800 ppi). The files are 18.7MB and 27.0MB, they were created with R's `tiff()` with `compression="lzw"`.

When I try to create a tile using

```
montage -compress lzw -tile 2x1 -geometry +0+0 Figure4L.tiff Figure4R.tiff Figure4.tiff
```

I get a file 12800x6400 TIFF which has a size of 12.8 MB, GIMP reports a resolution of 72 x 72 ppi.

GIMP also reports `"Warning:The image you are loading has 16 bits per channel. GIMP can only handle 8 bit, so it will be converted for you. Information will be lost because of this conversion."` which was not present in the initial images

What and why is being lost with the montage? Is the montaging lossless? Apparently not. Is there a better way to achieve my purpose without losing quality?

**UPDATE:** This might be related to how R writes TIFFs so I updated the tags. It might be also related to [TIFF plot generation and compression: R vs. GIMP vs. IrfanView vs. Photoshop file sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880558/tiff-plot-generation-and-compression-r-vs-gimp-file-sizes/20885003?noredirect=1#20885003)

Comment: does ImageMagick's `identify` function help you understand what's going on?

Comment: Nope, not really Ben.

Comment: I'm not fond of TIFFs anyway.  Any chance you can work with PNGs and convert to TIFF at the end?

Comment: I would gladly throw TIFF out of the window but the publisher wants EPS or TIFFs (<10MB) and because its a contour plot with a smooth color transitions i can't do EPS (30-40 MB files).

Comment: that's why I suggested that you generate PNGs, stick them together with `montage`, then use `convert` to change them to TIFFs as a last step ... ?  (I have seen a lot of publishers require TIFF or EPS. It mystifies me a little bit that they are stuck on these old formats ... I don't know what the advantages to them would be over PNG/PDF ...)

Comment: Totally agree with you. I still can't understand why they don't move to PNG/SVG. OK thanks will try that but it's still weird don't you think?

Comment: Yes (but I don't know how to answer your question ... hopefully someone else will enlighten us).

Comment: I tend to think that something is wrong with R rather than with Gimp or IrfanView. I am not on Windows so I cannot try Photoshop.